# Autofill breaks with one record [Excel-VBA]

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

My records start in cell B8, and I need to count them in Column A, starting in cell A8.

I used the answer from this question "[autofill down according to adjacent column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822756/autofill-down-according-to-adjacent-column)" but how do I handle when the recordcount is 0 or 1? When there is 1 record, it errors. Seems Autofill can't autofill one cell.

I have some conditions testing for zero and one, but is there a cleaner way to do it?

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row    'Find last row        

If LastRow >= 8 Then                            'If recordcount is 1 or greater
    Range("A8").FormulaR1C1 = "1"               'First number is "1"
        If Not LastRow = 8 Then                 'If not recordcount exactly 1 
           'Enumerate the remaining records with Autofill
            Range("A8").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A8:A" & LastRow), Type:=xlLinearTrend      
        End If
 End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has two tested methods to accomplish what you are trying to do.  The first method is what you were already using, removing the elements that were preventing it from working.  The second is another method to examine, because it might give you ideas for a future project that has similar requirements but using autofill isn't what is required.

**TESTED**

```
Sub AutoFiller()

Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row    'Find last row

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, 1) = 1                'First number is "1"
    Range("A8").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A8:A" & LastRow), Type:=xlLinearTrend             
End Sub
```

**Using LOOP instead of Autofill:**

```
Sub VBAAutoFill()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim count As Long

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 
    count = 1

    For lRow = 8 to LastRow
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 1) = count
        count = count + 1
    Next lRow
end Sub
```

**EXCEL FUNCTION:**  count all your entries, if you just want to know how many there are total..

```
COUNTA(B8:B10000)
```

edit notes:  elaborating on process in notes, correcting typos.  Original edit added solutions.

Answer (score 1):

`My records start in cell B8, and I need to count them in Column A, starting in cell A8.`

I'm taking this to mean that, you are essentially enumerating the rows.  This should be helpful to resolve your error issues, and if it's not exactly what you want in the `A` column, it shouldn't be hard for you to make an adjustment:

```
 Public Sub GetRangeCount()

    Dim bRange As Range
    Set bRange = Range(Range("B8"), Range("B1048575").End(xlUp))

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    For Each c In bRange

        If c.Value <> "" Then
            i = i + 1
            c.Offset(0, -1).Value = i
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That will work.  Hard coding the 1048575 for the last row of B might be a bad idea in case people with slightly older versions of Excel use the formula.

Comment: You're right. Your example is better for broader reuse. I could change mine, but then the only real difference between our answers would be  `For` vs `For Each` and that my example skips the enumeration when it encounters a blank cell... which I'm not even sure the OP wants/needs.

Comment: Leave yours and let the OP choose, and let future readers find value in the variations.  It doesn't matter who gets the cred, as we both did that simultaneously.  Also, there will be people in the future who need what you did in some slightly different way just like the OP modified someone else's answer somewhere else.  Kudos..  Although, I would modify the LastRow, for the reasons, your answer is still different and valid.  Using For Each and Offset, and skipping any blanks (nice add)