# Summing across columns with fixed start cell to last column VBA

Tags: vba

I have a table which changes in size each time it is run. I want the last column to return the sum of all values of each row. The last row of the table returns the sum of each column which I've tried to edit so that it would return the sum of the rows in the last column

```
'Sums everything starting from "L16" to the last row in column L and drags formula across the last row until the last column
Range(Cells(LR, "L"), Cells(LR, lastcol)).Formula = "=sum(L16:L" & LR - 1 & ")"
'Doesn't work but I want it to sum everything starting from "L16" to the last column in row 16 and drag the formula to the last row
Range(Cells(16, lastcol), Cells(LR, lastcol)).Formula = "=sum(L16:16" & lastcol-1 & ")"
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17823255/2727437) to see about using autofill with vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a syntax error here `=sum(L16:16" & lastcol-1 & ")`, you need column letter before the row number.

If your lastcol isn't greater than 27 you can use the following statement:

```
Range(Cells(16, lastcol), Cells(LR, lastcol)).Formula = "=sum(L16:" & Chr(lastcol - 1 + 64) & "16)"
```

Alternatively, add this function to your project:

```
Function ColLetter(Col As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, Col).Address(True, False), "$")
    ColLetter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

It returns a letter of any column number you supply.
Then in your code you can use it like this:

```
Range(Cells(16, lastcol), Cells(LR, lastcol)).Formula = "=sum(L16:" & ColLetter(lastcol - 1) & "16)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! The table size does vary when I run this macro for different files, is there a way to work around the code you gave me if the lastcol is greater than 27

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use Chr() function to get column letter for columns after Z, but I've added an alternative way above that will work with the entire sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your data starts but that can be set with iStartCol & iStartRow.  It will put a sum formula at the end of each row & column, and also a grand total.

```
Sub Test()
Dim iStartCol As Long
Dim iStartRow As Long
iStartCol = 2       ' Starting Column of your Data
iStartRow = 11      ' Starting Row of your Data

Dim iTotalCol As Long   ' Find where the Total Column will be
iTotalCol = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1

Dim iTotalRow As Long   ' Find where the Total Row will be
iTotalRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

' Total Row
Sheet1.Range(Cells(iTotalRow, iStartCol), Cells(iTotalRow, iTotalCol - 1)).Formula = "=Sum(R[-" & iTotalRow - iStartRow & "]C:R[-1]C)"

' Total Cols
' Note: no -1 in Range so we will also sum the Total Row, for grand total
Sheet1.Range(Cells(iStartRow, iTotalCol), Cells(iTotalRow, iTotalCol)).Formula = "=Sum(RC[-" & iTotalCol - iStartCol & "]:RC[-1])"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I tried editing your code with mine but it doesn't compile. I get an application defined or object defined error when I get to the third line


    `StartCol = 12`


    `StartRow = 16`


    `TotalCol = Cells(16, Columns.Count + 1).End(xlToLeft).Column`


    `TotalRow = Cells(Rows.Count + 1, 12).End(xlUp).Row`


    `Range(Cells(TotalRow, StartCol), Cells(TotalRow, TotalCol - 1)).Formula = "=Sum(R[-" & TotalRow - StartRow & "]C:R[-1]C)"`


    `Range(Cells(StartRow, TotalCol), Cells(TotalRow, TotalCol)).Formula = "=Sum(RC[-" & TotalCol - StartCol & "]:RC[-1])"`

Comment: You only need to change the starting values, the code will determine total row/col for you.  the line: `TotalCol = Cells(16, Columns.Count + 1).End(xlToLeft).Column` is failing for you because totalcol is a long, and .column returns a range.